# How to comment multiple lines in TeXworks (MiKTeX default editor)?

Tags: texworks, comments

I would like to comment multiple lines in TeXworks (installed as part of MiKTeX) and I need to know the keyboard trick for commenting/uncommenting at once.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MiKTeX installs the [TeXworks](http://tug.org/texworks) editor as standard. This has the ability to add/remove comments from multiple line (placing `%` at the start) using the shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> (insert comment)/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> (remove comment). The key binds can be customised (particularly useful if your keyboard makes these combinations inconvenient).

Comment: Thanks @JosephWright. One question: what is best editor for Windows operating system?

Comment: @Stephen There is no 'best' editor: we have a list of editors with features lists: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides